# EXCEL I'm trying to "link" between two tables, how can I do that?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working in Excel.
I have 2 sheets and in them I have 2 columns in each sheet.
The product columns not in the same order but every product on Sheet2 appear on Sheet1.
I want to sum all values of the products that are in "Europe" for example, so I need to run on the list of the products on Sheet2 but while I'm running I need to see the products as continents (from Sheet1), how can I do that?
I've tried to use SUMIF but I can't make this work.
**I can't combine the tables, or change anything.

Sheet1:
Product---Continent
TV----------Asia
Watch-----America
Stove------Europe

Sheet2:
Product----Value

Watch-----50

TV---------100

Stove------20

Thanks for the help.

Comment: With a SQL database, this would be easy ... you could create one (e.g. MS Access) and then link the tables to it.

Answer (score 0):

For example, try:

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A2:A6,D2:D6,B2:B6,"Europe")*E2:E6)
```